# Sandboxed scripting

Tags: security, scripting, sandbox

I'm interested in how I could use a scripting language to execute simple blocks of code in a sandboxed manner. The host language/environment could be c#/ruby/python/java (anything but c). But the scripting language could equally be something obscure such as javascript/python/ruby/perl etc.

What I want is a way of executing script with traditional programming constructs i.e. conditionals/loops/date manipulation/arrays etc. But what I don't want is to expose things such as IO, connectivity to http streams, databases etc.

I'm currently looking at spidermonkey using the python adapter, but I wondered if there were other options that I should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with .NET (VB, C#, any language) via [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0.aspx) - set the policy on the machine to not allow access to any Framework classes you like.

See [Setting Security Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03kwzyfc.aspx).

By default the policy allows code that originated on the local machine to do anything; you can set it so that by default, code cannot call into the I/O classes, cannot do HTTP connections, and so on.

Comment: On the back of this comment I started looking at boo I wanted an extensible language as well as some nice dynamism. I suddenly realize that the CLR is a great platform, and I believe that one day C# will be a java like dinosaur but the CLR will live for quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

Lua is very easy to sandbox code in. Here's a reference on the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes). It's a terrific minimalist scripting language, easy to embed in other (C or C++) code. So your host would be Lua embedded in some other code (or just the factory-installed Lua interpreter). Your scripting language would be Lua.

If you don't know it, though, I'm sure there are other good solutions that don't require you to learn a new language.